# ImportError: No module named ROOT when using yoda2root

Tags: python, homebrew, root-framework, pyroot

I'm trying to convert a yoda file produced by a Rivet analysis into a Root file. When I try to do this, I get the error:

```
yoda2root Rivet.yoda test.root

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/yoda2root", line 24, in module
import ROOT
ImportError: No module named ROOT
```

I installed everything using Homebrew, except Yoda as the version in homebrew was older and was incompatible.

When looking at similar problems that people have had, often the answer was to set the $PYTHONPATH, but I have tried this and it has had no affect - though I could be setting it incorrectly.

I also cannot find PyROOT anywhere (Perhaps this is the problem?), should this have been installed with Homebrew?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your environment variables so that python sees ROOT bindings:

```
pushd $(brew --prefix root) >/dev/null; . libexec/thisroot.sh; popd >/dev/null
```